# Replace "Sale" badge by "Out of Stock" in Woocommerce archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, badge

I am working on woocommerce shop and here is [the link of the website shop page](http://shop.suvidhamitra.com/)

On this page the first product is `out of stock`. I would like to show `Out of stock` instead of "Sale!" badge on the image.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the loop/sale-flash.php template you can see it has a filter for the sale flash. You can add this to your functions.php file to modify that output.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', 'sale_flash_stock_status' );
function sale_flash_stock_status( $output_html, $post, $product ){
    if( $product->is_in_stock() ){
        // Leave the sale flash unchanged if it's in stock.
        return $output_html;
    }
    else {
        // Change the html output custom stock status
        $output_html = '<span class="stock-status">' . esc_html__( 'Out of stock', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>'
        return $output_html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add in the functions.php file of your theme:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_flash', 'woocommerce_custom_sale_text', 10, 3);
function woocommerce_custom_sale_text($text, $post, $_product)
{
    return '<span class="onsale">out of stock</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will add, on Woocommerce archives pages (as shop), a "Out of Stock" badge for out of stock products replacing the "Sale!" badge when products are on sale:

```
// Add badge  "Out of stock" (and replace sale badge)
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title','custom_before_shop_loop_item_title', 2 ); // Archives pages
function custom_before_shop_loop_item_title(){
    remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash', 10 );
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash', 6 ); // For storefront theme
    add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title','show_product_loop_outofstock_badge', 10 );
}

function show_product_loop_outofstock_badge(){
    global $post, $product;

    if ( $product->get_stock_status() == 'outofstock' ) :
        echo '<span class="onsale outofstock">'. esc_html__('Out of stock', 'woocommerce') .'</span>';
    elseif ( $product->is_on_sale() ) :
        echo '<span class="onsale">'. esc_html__( 'Sale!', 'woocommerce' ) .'</span>';
    endif;
}
```

> You might have to make some hook priority changes, depending on your theme. This code support also storefront theme.

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]